# How do I get my button a little bit up?

Tags: html, css, button, authentication, indexing

A screenshot: [image: http://i60.tinypic.com/24mf69l.png]

So, I want that Login button a little bit up, exactly next to the Password form. I'm since 15:00 A.M. busy with it, (Dutch time), and it's really being stressful.

I need quick help. Also, I marked somethings red, because the site is running on my IP.

Ow, and I already tried margin-top, but it just doesn't work?

Comment: please paste the full login form code into your question (click the edit link) wrapped by the `login-box` div and the pertaining css code (eg. `input[type="submit"]`)...

Comment: also include the css code for classes `input`, `pass` and `user`...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to move the login button, you can add some CSS to it:

```
button {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess...

You should try reducing the `width` of the login button a little bit and see if it goes up. ;)